# How to softly end a process using VBS

Tags: vbscript, process

I like to end a process using VBScript.
Unfortunally I only found examples in which the authors are describing how to do it killing the process.

I like to ask for closing. So objProcess.Terminate() won't help.

I'm using Windows XP SP3 with admin rights.

Any Ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to shutdown a VBSCript process gracefully, or use VBScript to shutdown some other process gracefully?

Comment: @Kornkreismuster a process can be 'killed softly', if it can receive the message "please terminate gracefully" and 'knows'/is programmed to react to such a message. I understand that you want to terminate your own VBScripts gracefully - then it should be easy to specify/publish what (kind of) actions must be done in that case. In order to think about the message passing, it would be good to know, how you start/under what host you run those scripts.

Comment: There had been some jerk editing my question. Indeed, I like to end an other process gracefully using VB-Script.

So I got a Javaw-Process with a shotdown-hook implemented. The challenge is to end this process. Sounds easy, but it isn't. After endless hours of research without finding a solution one idea was to try it with VBS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, finally I found a solution for my problem, but is not solved using VBS.
There is a program written to send a CTRL-BREAK to any process called "SendSignal". I had tried this before, but all my process was responding had been an error-message and it kept running.

I changed this program sending CTRL+C. After this I was able to shut my Javaw process gently.

Thanks to all, for your help!

Answer (score 0):

<s>You could try the `CloseMainWindow` and the `Close` methods on the process as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx), like:</s>

```
Sub KillingMeSoftly(processName)

    'partly copied from http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/processes/    
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & processName & "'")
    For Each objProcess in colProcessList
        objProcess.CloseMainWindow
        objProcess.Close
    Next

End Sub
```

*this was a bad answer*

**UPDATE**
While searching for an answer, I just discovered that starting a script with the //T:nn option triggers the Terminate event on objects:

```
class Foo
    sub class_terminate
        msgbox "Gracefull termination"
        ' Put your own termination code here.        
    end sub
end class

dim bar
set bar = new Foo

do 
loop ' makes the script run forever
```

Save this as `c:\endless.vbs`

Running this script will never trigger the termination event because it will hang in the endless loop, but if you start the script with a timeout it will; Start the script from the command prompt:
`C:\>wscript endless.vbs //T:5`

You'll see that after 5 seconds a messagebox with "Gracefull termination" appears.

This is usefull when you want to quit a script after a certain amount of time and run a cleanup if it was not ended by itself. I do not know if this covers the solution you are searching for.

Comment: If I try this with the calc.exe, I get a fault message: Object does not support "CloseMainWindow". Same thing, if I only try the "Close".
Also tried to add brackets, so CloseMainWindow() and Close().

Comment: Ok, that means that `CloseMainWindow` and `Close` are not available as COM method. What kind of application do you try to close?

Comment: @AutomatedChaos -1 for proposing to call a method "CloseMainWindow" (probably inspired by the eponymous method of the .NET System.Diagnostics.Process class) on an object of type WMI Win32_Process (and obfuscating the issue by blaming COM).

Comment: @AutomatedChaos --1 for puttings right; my upvote will be postponed until it's shown that the Class_Terminate can do its job reliably if the script is terminated.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner `Class_Terminate` works only when a script is stopped by the time-out that was set by the `//T:nn` option of `wscript.exe`. I tested it with `objProcess.Terminate` in the striked script above, but that will kill the process without triggering the Class_Terminate event. Actually, I really want to know what underlying method is used by `wscript.exe` to exit the process whilst the correct termination of object instances is still being performed.